# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'scp' expected at this point. End of demands.

Tags: grails

Doing an integration test in grails 1.3.7, I was mocking a method called 'scp', and the following exception occured:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'scp' expected at this point. End of demands.

'scp' was being called twice. The first time it worked, the second one it throwed the exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you mock a method, you can specify a range which indicates how many times you can call the method. Taken from the documentation:

> You then specify the name of the method that you want to mock with an optional range as its argument. This range determines how many times you expect the method to be called, so if the number of invocations falls outside of that range (either too few or too many) then an assertion error will be thrown. If no range is specified, a default of "1..1" is assumed, i.e. that the method must be called exactly once.

```
control.demand.scp(2..2){ file, todir, verb, pass -> return "" }
```

I couldn't find the reason for this error, so I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is strict mocking. You have to specify the number of times the method will called on the mocked object on demand. You can bypass strict mocking by passing a flag to [mockFor indicating loose mocking](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#mockingCollaborators).

Comment: Thanks for the tip dmahapatro, I was aware of the flag after I found what the error was about, but when it happened I couldn't figure out what was causing it. It's a nice option when you don't care how many times the method is called though. Thanks!